# Mips, tring to read a txt file into an array but always get last element

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

In my project, I required to read strings with a max of 10 characters and put them into an array. To achieve this, I read each line byte by byte, and if I get a "/n" line, I add the entire line into the array and move on to the next line. I can print each element to console reading from the array with no issue just after putting them in array in the "add_to_array:" however the problem is when I try to reach different elements of the array in the "read_done:" it always gives me the last element of the array.

```
Ex input:
mert
file
edit
20637
format
view
help
```

```
Ex output:
0mert
1file
2edit
320637
4format
5view
6help
help
Reading file is complete.
Size of Array: 7
-- program is finished running --
```

Note: I print them with their corresponding indexes in the "add_to_array:". But when I try to print any element in "read_done:" it will always print "help".

```
.data

buffer: .space 1    # 1 byte buffer in order to read the line byte by byte
line: .space 11     # Hard coded line size with max 11 byte long

array: .word 0:15   # An empty array of words with size of 1000
arraySize: .word 0

finName: .asciiz "D:/input.txt"


endl: .asciiz "\n"

soa : .asciiz "\nReading file is complete.\nSize of Array: "

foutInsertion:  .asciiz "insertion_sort_out.txt"      # filename for insertion sort output
foutSelection:  .asciiz "selection_sort_out.txt"      # filename for selection sort output
    
    
    .text
main:   # First we need to open txt file in order to read it
    la $s1 buffer
    la $s2 line
    li $s3 0            # current line length
    
      
    # Open file
    li $v0, 13      # System call code = 13 to open file
    la $a0, finName     # Input file name
    li $a1, 0       # Open for reading (flags are 0: read, 1: write)
    syscall         # Open the file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
    move $s0,$v0        # Save the file descriptor to read 

read_line:      
    
    #sw $zero, buffer       
    # Read file byte by byte
    li $v0, 14      # System call code = 14 to read file
    move $a0, $s0       # File descriptor
    la $a1, buffer      # The buffer that holds the byte
    la $a2, 1       # Hardcoded buffer lenght
    syscall         # Read the byte and write into the buffer


    blez $v0 read_done  # keep reading until bytes read <= 0
        
                        
        # naively handle exceeding line size by exiting
    slti $t0, $s3, 11
    beqz $t0, read_done

    lb $s4, ($s1)
    li $t0 10           # If current byte is a EOL (end of line)
    beq $s4 $t0 add_to_array    # Then add line to array

    # otherwise, append byte to line
    add $s5 $s3 $s2
    sb $s4 ($s5)
    
    # increment line length
    addi $s3 $s3 1

     b read_line

add_to_array:
    lw  $t0, arraySize  # Load current array size from memory
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # Increment size of array by one
    sw $t0, arraySize   # Save uptaded array size to memory
    

    add $s5 $s3 $s2     # null terminate line
    sb $zero ($s5)

    li $s3 0        # reset bytes read
    

    lw $t0, arraySize   # Add line to array
    addi $t0, $t0, -1   # Get corresponsing index 
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall
    
    la $t1, array       # Load base address of array into $t1
    mul $t0, $t0, 4     # Mul
    add $t1, $t1, $t0 
    sw $s2, 0($t1)
    
    # print line (or consume it some other way)
    li $v0 4
    lw $a0 0($t1)
    syscall

    # print newline
    li $a0 10
    li $v0 11
    syscall

    b read_line
    
read_done:  
    
    li $v0 4
    la $t2, array
    #mul $t2, $t2, 4    
    lw $a0 20($t2)
    syscall
   

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, soa
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 1
    lw $a0, arraySize
    syscall

    
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall         # Close the file
    
    
        li $v0 10
        syscall         # Exit the program
```

Comment: Well yeah, you read every line into the same memory (`line`), so of course old content is going to be overwritten by newer content.

Comment: But I modify the $t1 (which is address of array) by adding i*4

Comment: Doesn't matter, because `array` only holds the address of each string (which right now is always the same: `line`). The only place where you store actual character data is `line`, which you're re-using for each string, thereby overwriting any old content.

Comment: I see now. How exactly should I add lines to the array then?